# Error compiling for board NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module) with AzureIoT headers

Tags: iot

Hey guys am sure you are tired of seeing this question on many posts, truth is until now I have not come close to a solution and time is running out. 
Below is a sample of the error a, getting please help me in any way. Thanks

```
Arduino: 1.8.10 (Windows 10), Board: "NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module), 80 MHz, Flash, Legacy (new can return nullptr), All SSL ciphers (most compatible), 4MB (FS:2MB OTA:~1019KB), 2, v2 Lower Memory, Disabled, None, Only Sketch, 115200"

Multiple libraries were found for "AzureIoTUtility.h"
Used: C:\Users\Agent
Not used: C:\Users\Agent
Multiple libraries were found for "AzureIoTProtocol_MQTT.h"
In file included from C:\Users\Agent 
96\Documents\Arduino\libraries\AzureIoTUtility\src/azure_c_shared_utility/constbuffer.h:16:0,

Used: C:\Users\Agent
Not used: C:\Users\Agent
             from C:\Users\Agent 
96\Documents\Arduino\libraries\AzureIoTHub\src\internal/iothub_client_private.h:9,

Multiple libraries were found for "ArduinoJson.h"
Used: C:\Users\Agent
Not used: C:\Users\Agent
             from C:\Users\Agent    
96\Documents\Arduino\libraries\AzureIoTHub\src\iothub_client_ll_uploadtoblob.c:20:

    Multiple libraries were found for "DHT.h"
    C:\Users\Agent 96\Documents\Arduino\libraries\AzureIoTUtility\src/umock_c/umock_c_prod.h:114:30: 
    error: pasting "MOCKABLE_" and "/*this creates a new constbuffer from a memory area*/" does not give 
 a valid preprocessing token

 Used: C:\Users\Agent
#define EXPAND_PROD_ENTRY(A) MOCKABLE_##A

Multiple libraries were found for "ESP8266WiFi.h"
                           ^

Used: C:\Users\Agent
Multiple libraries were foun d for "AzureIoTHub.h"
Used: C:\Users\Agent
C:\Users\Agent 
96\Documents\Arduino\libraries\AzureIoTHub\src/azure_macro_utils/macro_utils_generated.h: 9020:1: 
note: in expansion of macro 'EXPAND_PROD_ENTRY'

 X(P1) \

 ^

 C:\Users\Agent 
96\Documents\Arduino\libraries\AzureIoTUtility\src/umock_c/azure_macro_utils/macro_utils.h:35:21: 
 note: in expansion of macro 'MU_FOR_EACH_1_9'

#define MU_C2_(x,y) x##y

                 ^

   C:\Users\Agent 96\Documents\Arduino\libraries\AzureIoTUtility\src/umock_c/umock_c_prod.h:119:5: note: 
   in expansion of macro 'MU_FOR_EACH_1'

 MU_FOR_EACH_1(EXPAND_PROD_ENTRY, __VA_ARGS__)

 ^

 C:\Users\Agent 
 96\Documents\Arduino\libraries\AzureIoTUtility\src/azure_c_shared_utility/constbuffer.h:35:1: note: 
 in expansion of macro 'MOCKABLE_INTERFACE'

MOCKABLE_INTERFACE(constbuffer,

 ^

    C:\Users\Agent 96\Documents\Arduino\libraries\AzureIoTUtility\src/umock_c/umock_c_prod.h:11     
   4:30: error: pasting "MOCKABLE_" and "/*this creates a new constbuffer from an existing BU 
   FFER_HANDLE*/" does not give a valid preprocessing token

   #define EXPAND_PROD_ENTRY(A) MOCKABLE_##A

                          ^

C:\Users\Agent 
96\Documents\Arduino\libraries\AzureIoTHub\src/azure_macro_utils/macro_utils_generated.h:9024:1: 
note: in expansion of macro 'EXPAND_PROD_ENTRY'

   X(P1) \

     ^  

  C:\Users\Agent 
  96\Documents\Arduino\libraries\AzureIoTHub\src/azure_macro_utils/macro_utils_generated.h:9021:1: 
 note: in expansion of macro 'MU_FOR_EACH_1_8'

   MU_FOR_EACH_1_8(X, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6, P7, P8, P9)

    ^

  C:\Users\Agent 
96\Documents\Arduino\libraries\AzureIoTUtility\src/umock_c/azure_macro_utils/macro_utils.h:35:21: 
  note: in expansion of macro 'MU_FOR_EACH_1_9'

   #define MU_C2_(x,y) x##y

                 ^

 C:\Users\Agent 96\Documents\Arduino\libraries\AzureIoTUtility\src/umock_c/umock_c_prod.h:119:5: 
 note: in expansion of macro 'MU_FOR_EACH_1'

 MU_FOR_EACH_1(EXPAND_PROD_ENTRY, __VA_ARGS__)

   ^

   C:\Users\Agent 
  96\Documents\Arduino\libraries\AzureIoTUtility\src/azure_c_shared_utility/constbuffer.h:35:1: note: 
 in expansion of macro 'MOCKABLE_INTERFACE'

MOCKABLE_INTERFACE(constbuffer, 

^

 C:\Users\Agent 96\Documents\Arduino\libraries\AzureIoTHub\src\iothub_client_ll_uploadtoblob.c:26:27: 
 fatal error: internal/blob.h: No such file or directory

    #include "internal/blob.h"

                       ^

  compilation terminated.

exit status 1
Error compiling for board NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module).
```

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.

Comment: I think you may need to reinstall your development environment. Its finding multiple copies of many files, and missing one. It may be just a matter of configuration or an environment variable.

Comment: @NomadMaker Alright thanks, lemme try that.

Comment: @NomadMaker I tried to do as you said but unfortunately, it's to no avail :(

Comment: It looks like you're using the Arduino compiler system. I've used it to compile code for some other systems (Teensy for one) and I had similar problems a while ago.